# How to remove active class on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//remove active tabs on load
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('.tab').removeClass('active_tab');
        jQuery('.tab_content').removeClass('active_tab_content');
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );//end
```

I try using the above code to close specific tabs that are normally opened on load. I not sure why it's not working so far. I am using the code on a child theme of the Enfold theme. Any help will be appreciated.

My current URL is [CMSDeployed](http://cmsdeployed.com)

Comment: Instead of `.tab` and `active_tab`, try both names equal like `$('.active_tab').removeClass('active_tab');` .. maybe

Comment: no it doesn't work. maybe viewing the PHP that create the tab will be helpfull. http://paste.ofcode.org/37Yf3KaL3NW55ez8rvTqrN3 actually it works when I comment out lines 228 and 229. But I need to be able to clause all as well.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Just for a test, wrap your _removeClass-line_ with `setTimeout(function(){ /* your line here */ }, 3000);`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to use a javascript snippet inside a php function.

That is not going to work.

Php functions are going to be executed on the server while JS functions are going to be run on client side and on the browser.

Everytime you call that PHP function, it is going to print out that javascript snippet or whatever is inside that block.

Comment: That is not quiet the issue. I included the code directly into the header without the php and still no result.